# Can I register my iPhone to multiple Dev accs?

Tags: iphone, ipad

So I've got my iPhone and it's already registered to my friend's Dev Acc, because I'm helping him to test his app. But I want to register as an Apple Dev and of course I want to add my iPhone to my acc.
Is it possible to it will registered to multiple accs?
Did anybody tried this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. Just add the UDID to both accounts and install and select the appropriate profiles in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes mahn.A device can be associated with as many developer accounts as needed.There is no any limitation on it.To elaborate, a developer account may have multiple provision files and you can have many provisioning profiles on a single device.:)